# Python Serverless (SLS): Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, serverless-framework

I am working on a project that is using AWS CodeBuild to deploy a Serverless (SLS) function that is written in Python.

The deployment works fine within code build. It successfully creates the function and I can view the lambda within the Lambda AWS UI. Whenever the function is triggered, I get the error seen below:

```
Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'some/function': attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

It is extremely frustrating as I know the function exists at that directory listed above. During the CodeBuild script, I can `ls` into the directory and confirm that it indeed exists. The function is defined in my serverless.yml file as follows:

```
functions:
  file-blaster:
    runtime: python3.7
    handler: some/function.function_name
    events:
      - existingS3:
          bucket: some_bucket
          events:
            - s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: ${opt:stage}/some/prefix
```

Sadly, I haven't been able to crack this one. Has anyone had a similar experience while working with SLS and python in the cloud?

It seems odd that SLS would build and deploy successfully, but the Lambda itself cant find the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be a short answer for what is a somewhat longer discussion on Python imports. You can do the research yourself on the hectic and confusing battle between relative and absolute imports as a design for a python project.

The Gist:
It is necessary to understand that the base of the python importing for SLS functions *IS* where the `serverless.yml` file exists (I imagine that it is similar to having a `main.py` that calls the other files that are referenced as "functions" in the sls yml). For my case above, I did not structure the imports using absolute imports when I had my issues. I switched all of my imports to have absolute paths, so when I moved the package around, it would continue to work.

The error that I was given `Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'some/function': attempted relative import with no known parent package` was really poor to describe the actual issue. The error should have included that the packages being used by `some/function` were not found when attempting a relative import because that was the actual problem that needed fixing.

Hopefully this helps someone else out someday. Let me know if I can provide more information where I haven't already.

Comment: oh, now i got the clear view of your problem and absolutely it will help others.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change your handler property from :

```
handler: some/function.function_name
```

to

```
handler: some/function.{lambda handler name}
```

like, my folder structure is:

```
- some
  - function1.py
```

then my template will be:

```
functions:
  file-blaster:
    runtime: python3.7
    handler: some/function1.lambda_handler
```

for more details check here https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/